# Option selected not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple code:

```
<span>
<label for="cmp_sort">Sort by</label>
   <select id="cmp_sort">
        <option value="original" selected="selected">original</option>
        <option value="name">name</option>
   </select>&nbsp;
```

In all browsers, including ie7-8, after loading page default value in combobox is "original". But IE9 show nothing (empty line). When i press on that line i'll receive "original/name" as i needed.
I try to do  `$("cmp_sort").val("original")` on document.load, but its not help. However, when i execute this code in console, all works fine. What should i do? Thanks.

Comment: working for my on IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/u8XFP/

Comment: As pointed out by @Mathachew It should be `$('#cmp_sort')` and try to crear your cache.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the hash tag:

`$("#cmp_sort").val("original")`

`$("cmp_sort")` will look for any html tags called `cmp_sort`, which don't exist.

Comment: ohh. me bad. Thanks, and sorry for fool question.